# There is an inconsistency extracting OBJ

Tags: autodesk-forge

We started to notice some inconsistency while extracting OBJ file using `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/manifest`

Sometimes there is a role as obj (`"role":"obj"`) when the model manifest is completed however sometimes there is no obj role when exactly the same file was processed.

What is the reason of this inconsistency? How to prevent it?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why the "role" would be missing in certain scenarios, so I'm thinking it's likely a bug. In that case I'd suggest to contact `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and include as much information as possible (e.g., your Forge application client ID, one example URN where the "role" is present, and one where it isn't, link back to this Stack Overflow question, etc.).